# Cron Jobs in Jquery

Tags: jquery, cron

I am intending to write a cron job with HTML5 and JQuery Mobile(versions - 1.10.2,ui and 1.4.3, mobile). I am using the plugin  [jquery-cron](http://shawnchin.github.io/jquery-cron/) and have written the following code snippet.

HTML -->

```
 <div data-role="page" id="cron">
 <div data-role="header" data-fullscreen="true" class="center-div"><h2>HEADER</h2>  </div>
<div data-role="content">
<div id='selector'> Division for Cron </div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true" class="center-div"><h3>FOOTER</h3></div>
</div>
```

Jquery -->

```
 $('#selector').cron({
    initial: "10 11 * * *",
   onChange: function() {
        $('#example1-val').text($(this).cron("value"));

},
useGentleSelect: true // default: false /
});
```

How can i set the interval in which i need to perform some task repeatatively, even if the browser window is closed . and where to write the function which needs to be performed on start of the Job . I understand how to set the interval , ie like */5 * * * * this simply means every 5 seconds but where to set this. Kindly help

Comment: Javascript runs in the browser. If the browser isn't running, your code won't run.

Comment: It also has to be in a web page that's open. When you close the page, its scripts stop running, unless you use this in a browser extension that runs in the background.

Comment: You can't run jQuery (or any client side script for that matter) when the browser window is closed. From what I see, this script sends an Ajax-request to the server at an interval. The processing is done serverside. If you close the browser, the cron will never run.

Comment: Ok got it . but what is i package this with phonegap. and want this application to run at specific time interval. pretty much like the facebook app refreshes every 1 hour even if it is not open.

Comment: and kindly help me with where to write the function of cron job and where to set the time interval